# "Could you help me [to] review this document?"

Tags: to-infinitive

Should we use *to* after the verb "help"? Are both of the following sentences correct?

> Could you help me to review this document?
>
> Could you help me review this document?

Comment: Both patterns are correct, with or without "to".

Comment: **help** accepts a nominal (to-infinitive) complement or an action (bare infinitive) complement.  *Could you help paint the house? Could you help to paint the house?*  But  not a gerund. [no]Could you help painting the house? [/no] There we'd say *help **with** painting the house*

Comment: it feels please is missing from the question. Where should it go?